# How do I get meaningful results from gprof on an MPI code?

Tags: mpi, hpc, gprof

I am optimising an MPI code and I am working with Gprof. 
The problem is that the results I obtained are completely unreasonable. My workflow is the following:

- compiling the code adding `-pg` as a compilation flag.
- running the code `mpirun -np Nproc EXEC.exe arg1 ... argN`.
- running gprof on the executable `gprof EXEC.exe`

What's wrong in this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instructions for running `gprof` typically assume the program is serial, or single process but multi-threaded.

To run `gprof` with a multi-process program like an MPI program, you'll want to

1. make sure each process outputs its own file
2. explicitly sum the files across processes
3. run `gprof` on the results.

[This blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20200226032601/http://shwina.github.io/2014/11/profiling-parallel) or [these instructions at LLNL](https://hpc.llnl.gov/software/development-environment-software/gprof) are good starting points:

1. Set the poorly documented `GMON_OUT_PREFIX` environment variable, e.g. in bash, `export GMON_OUT_PREFIX=gmon.out-` before running the mpiexec command (then, depending on the environment, you may have to run `mpirun -x GMON_OUT_PREFIX -np Nproc EXEC.exe arg1 ... argN` to make sure each process has the environment variable)
2. Use gprof itself to collect and sum the results, `gprof -s EXEC.exe gmon.out-*`
3. `gprof EXEC.exe gmon.sum` (or just examine the individual files, or the files collectively, with `gprof EXEC.exe gmon.out-12345` or `gprof EXEC.exe gmon.out-*`)